# Special eyed3 type becomes python's NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, eyed3

I've written a little script to move all my .flac files from dap to artist subfolders so it can easily be accessed from computer. I used python3 on Ubuntu with libs such as eyed3 and os. And it worked fine with almost 30 songs (2 artists).
So here is the code:

```py
    import os
    import eyed3

    os.chdir("/home/user/Music")
    cwd = os.getcwd()

    # print the current directory
    print("Current working directory is:", cwd)

    listOfFiles = os.listdir()
    artists = []

    # print(listOfFiles)

    try:
        for file in listOfFiles:
            aFile = eyed3.load(file)
            artist = aFile.tag.artist
            if artist not in a:
                artists.append(artist)
                os.mkdir(artist)
            os.rename(cwd + '/' + file, cwd + '/' + artist + '/' + file)
    except:
        print("not a file")

    print(artists)
```

It created 2 folders as it has to.
But when I tried to run this script on my Windows PC it trows an exception and prints "not a file".
Here is console output without try/except:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\GitHub\Song-Sorter\main.py", line 21, in <module>
    artist = aFile.tag.artist
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

So I tried this (next line after `artist = aFile.tag.artist`):

```py
print(type(artist))
```

and its output is:

`<class 'NoneType'>`

What is the problem? Can't figure out

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe some file doesn't have information about `artist` - you should check this file in other program.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I tested this script on my mp3 part of library and it worked fine. Then I tried on flac part and it did not work because eyed3 works only with mp3. So I recomend using Mutagen library